# Track file moves with git when splitting file during refactoring

Tags: git

During some refactoring, I am splitting a file foo into two new files foo1 and foo2. Some lines of foo end up in foo1, others in foo2 and the original foo ceases to exist with the refactoring commit. I can git mv foo to either foo1 or foo2 so that when looking at that file's diff in the refactoring commit or the log of that file its legacy is preserved but git always treats the other destination as a new file.  Is there a way to have git track the move to both destinations?

Comment: Take a look at [this blog post](http://computerscienceunveiled.blogspot.com/2016/07/split-and-move-file-using-git-while.html) that seems to address the problem. In it he gives a link to [this explanation](https://github.com/aoancea/git-history#split-a-file). Not sure if there's a more elegant or built-in way to do it, but hopefully that points you in the right direction!

Comment: @thisisbenmanley: thanks, that looks promising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a fundamental level, Git does not *record* file rename (move) operations at all, nor copies, nor anything of that sort.  So there's nothing special that you *have* to do.  But there are a few things you might *want* to do, or might not want to, depending on how you use Git and what you anticipate doing in the future.

Start with this: the basic unit of storage in Git is the commit.  A commit holds a full and complete snapshot of *all* of the files—all of the data for that commit—plus some metadata, or information *about* the commit itself: who made it (author and committer), when (date and time stamps for author and committer), and so on.

When you are the author-and-committer, you get to supply a *log message* in which you tell your future self, and anyone else, *why* you made *this particular* commit.  Don't describe *what* you did—Git can tell you that on its own—but rather *why* you did it.  For instance, you might rename file X to Y and copy it to Z, even though the result does not compile, and write a log message like: *Renamed file X to Y and copied it to Z in preparation for splitting classes during refactoring.  This commit should not be built, it is only for recording purposes.*

Or, you might not do that exactly as is.  You might instead rename X to Y, copy Y to Z, then edit both Y and Z, all *before* making the commit.  The log message might be: *Refactored $thing.  Note that there was a single class X and now there are both Y and Z instead.*  This might include related changes as well, and this commit might compile; or you might save a commit in which they still don't actually compile yet: all you did was rename the class.

Either way, Git is just going to record, in the new snapshot, *all* of your files: you'll no longer have X, and this time you'll have new Y and Z.  So why would you commit a non-working intermediate commit that *only* renames-and-copies?  That seems kind of senseless, and maybe it *is* senseless and you shouldn't do it.  But maybe you want to do it anyway, or something like it, and this is where *how* Git works comes into play.

Every commit is just a snapshot plus this metadata.  One of the pieces of metadata is the hash ID of the commit that comes *before* this particular commit.  When you ask Git to *show* you a commit—as in `git show hash` or similar—Git extracts both the "before" commit and the commit itself, and then *compares* the two, as if you ran `git diff parent-hash hash`.  In fact, `git show` has the Git diff engine built into it, and runs it with a few options set; `git diff` takes most of the same command-line options as `git diff`.

When `git diff` compares one commit to another, if the left-side commit has some file X and the right-side file *doesn't* have X, but does have files Y and Z that aren't in the left-side snapshot, Git will consider that maybe, just maybe, file X was *renamed* to either Y or Z.  This rename detection is based on how similar the *contents* of X (in the left-side commit) are to those of Y and Z (in the right-side commit).

Rename detection is enabled by the `--find-renames` option.  This option takes an optional similarity percentage number, e.g., `--find-renames=50%` means that the left and right side files should be at least 50% similar to be considered "renamed".  This `--find-renames` option used to be *off* by default, but since Git 2.9, it is *on* by default.  The default similarity requirement is 50%, both before the flag was on by default, and now that it is; use the `--find-renames=setting` option to set the threshold higher or lower than 50%.

There is a similar flag, `--find-copies`, with an additional flag spelled `--find-copies-harder`.  The `--find-copies` flag takes an optional similarity percentage number, just like `--find-renames`, but as of today it's still not on by default, nor is the `--find-copies-harder` option.  [The documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) will tell you that `--find-copies-harder` is computationally expensive, which is why it's not on by default, and that `--find-copies` by default only finds copies if the source file appears to be changed.

This should make you wonder what it means for a file to be *changed*.  After all, each commit is just a snapshot.  No files are *changed* in a commit, they just *exist* in the commit.  ***Changed* is a property of the comparison of two different commits, not of one single commit.**  So what it means is that `--find-copies` will detect that file Z is a copy of file X if and only if the X on the left is *different* from the X on the right.

But what if X was *renamed* from X-on-the-left to Y-on-the-right?  Ideally, Git should consider this "changed".  Git will certainly consider it changed if the *contents* of X aren't a 100% match to the *contents* of the found-as-renamed Y, once X and Y are paired up by `--find-renames`.

What this means is that if you use `--find-copies`, perhaps with its slower mode `--find-copies-harder`, *with* `--find-renames`, Git should *automatically* detect that file X was copied-and-changed into files Y and Z *as long as they meet the similarity threshold*.  If you *just* copy the file, so that X is 100% similar to both Y and Z, that will definitely meet any required similarity threshold.<sup>1</sup>  So `git show` on *that* commit, when you enable rename and copy detection, should show you the rename-and-copy.'

If you make the whole system actually work, all in one commit, you end up with a nice compile-able commit.  That's better from a non-Git point of view, for sure.  But now file X might not be at least 50% similar to both files Y and Z, and if so, you'll need to lower the rename and/or copy similarity to get Git to auto-detect the renames and copies.

In general, it's not a great idea to distort your commits just to make the VCS happy.  But it might also help future-you remember what present-day you is about to do; if so, you're not distorting the commits for the *VCS*, but rather for the future person who's looking through the commits to see what happened.  So the choice is yours: multiple commits, with intermediate results, to help future-people see what's going on; or one commit that builds and runs, to help future-people not have to deal with intermediate commits when they explore what is, to them, the past.

---

<sup>1</sup>We're still left with the question as to whether Git considers a rename to be "modifying" the source file, so that X can be a source for the copy operation.  If it can't, you might want to at least change the class names in Y and Z, so that the two files are (say) 95% similar instead of 100% similar.